# Atualizar todos os registos da tabela com SQLiteDatabase.update()

Tags: android, sql-update

Tenho o seguinte código para fazer a atualização de um campo na minha tabela.
Gostaria de saber se teria como eu alterar os campos "nota" e "falta" em todos os registos da tabela.

Exemplo: colocar todas os registos com nota = 8 e falta = 5

```
public void Update_Exercicios(String id,int dados1,int dados2) {
    ContentValues valores= new ContentValues();
    valores.put("nota",dados1);
    valores.put("falta",dados2);
    banco.update("CriarTreinoExercicio", valores,"ID=?",new String[] {id});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer alterar todos os registos então não deve definir a clausula *WHERE*.

O método [update()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) tem 4 parâmetros que da esquerda para a direita são:

1 - **String:** Nome da tabela a alterar.
2 - **ContentValues:** Mapa com os nomes dos campos a alterar e os respectivos novos valores.
3 - **String:** A clausula *WHERE* a aplicar durante o *update*.
4 - **String[]:** Argumentos a passar à clausula *WHERE*

Na chamada ao método `update()`:

```
banco.update("CriarTreinoExercicio", valores,"ID=?",new String[] {id});
```

está a ser passado no 3º parâmetro, aquele que indica a clausula *WHERE*, um valor que será traduzido como `WHERE ID = id`, sendo apenas alterado o registo que tenha esse `id`.

Para alterar todos os registos deverá passar `null` no 3º e 4º parâmetros:

```
banco.update("CriarTreinoExercicio", valores, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta alterando a linha:

```
banco.update("CriarTreinoExercicio", valores,"ID=?",new String[] {id});
```

Para:

```
 banco.update("CriarTreinoExercicio", valores,"ID=ID",new String[] {id});
```

Ou para:

```
banco.update("CriarTreinoExercicio", valores,null,null);
```

Ou para:

```
banco.update("CriarTreinoExercicio", valores);
```

A ultima opção é a mais correta, porém não lembro se é possível, por tanto tenta na ordem de baixo para cima.